# How to enable paste option on right click of spark combo box flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex3

I want to get paste option on right clicking on the spark combobox to paste the clipboard copied text. How to do this in flex 4 spark combobox.
Thanks

Comment: Are you building a browser based app targeting Flash Player, or something else?  Really the cut and paste functionality is a system thing and I'm not sure how much control you'll have.  ActionScript does have some clipboard functionality, but I thought it was for It is possible to put stuff into the clipboard, but I don't know if you can pull stuff out.

Comment: ya it is a web application and the requirement is whenever user copy any text and he should paste it in the spark combobox by right clicking on it.currently user can press ctrl v to paste the copied text.But i need right click also to paste the copied text.Can any one help me in this

Comment: Our AutoComplete; which extends the ComboBox shows the paste option if you right click inside the TextInput: https://www.flextras.com/AutoCompleteComboBox/Samples/FlextrasZombie/ .  I'm no sure why your code would not show that.

Comment: I am getting only print,debugger, flashplayer and other options but not paste and select all.. dont know why thats y  i asked here.I kept my combobox in title window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution:

1. Set the mouseEnabled property true to  TitleWindow
2. In the creationComplete handler of TitleWindow, set `this.skin.enabled = true`